# Check link by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

There is a block of links,

```
<div class="links">
<a href="http://google.com">
<a href="http://bing.com">
<a href="http://example.com/section2/">
</div>
```

They are all placed in the html of `http://example.com/`.

How do I check each one, is it a link to currently opened site?

Script should give true to `http://example.com/anything/else/in/the/url/` and false to all others site.

Comment: What do you mean with 'a currently opened site'? One which the user has opened in a tab currently?

Comment: same domain? same sub-domain? same directory? http + https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out my jQuery plugin $.urlParser at GitHub: https://github.com/Dyvor/jquery/tree/master/plugins/urlParser

You could try the following code:

```
var current_host = $.urlParser(window.location.toString()).host;
$('div.links a').each(function() {
    if ( current_host == $.urlParser($(this).attr('href')).host ) {
        // the hosts matched ... place your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice plugin Dyvor. Instead of `attr('href')` you should consider using `$(this).href` in case the link points to a location on the same host, eg `<a href="hello.html">`. See the difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/c78wb/

Answer (score 1):

Give your DIV an ID to make it a bit easier:

```
<div id="links">
```

and then this script will do what you want:

```
var links = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].href.indexOf('http://mysite.com/') === 0) {
    // Yes, this link belongs to your site
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do it

```
$("a").each(function(){
  return $(this).attr("href").indexOf("http://mysite.com")==0;
});
```

Another way

```
$("a[href^='http://mysite.com/']")
```

will only give you the links you need